# Is it possible to create 0-code (trivial) app using data binding and Entity Framework? How?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, data-binding, visual-studio-2010

I tried following the steps I describe below in VS 2010, but to no avail:

- Create new Windows Forms App. Project
- Add new empty ADO EDM to Project
- Add new entity Customer with scalar properties FirstName and LastName
- Generate db script
- Execute db script to create tables in db
- Add new Object Data Source based on EDM Model1
- Select object Customer in Data Sources window and drop it on form in form of Details view.
- All typical binding controls are created, all I need to do is to enable the Save button.

I run the app, form is displayed. I can add new records and navigate between them. I press save, but when I reinitialize the app, all data is lost.

Is it possible to make this work with 0 code, if not, what is the minimum I should add to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Actually I think it has nothing to do with Entity Framework or Windows Forms...</strike>

By default, the "Copy to output directory" setting for database files is set to "Copy always", so the db file used by your program is overwritten every time you compile... Change the option to "Copy if newer", it should solve the problem

OK, apparently it was not the problem...

Actually you can't do it without writing any code : you still need to call SaveChanges on the ObjectContext to persist the changes made on the entities.

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

---

UPDATE : [here's a full working example](http://tomlev.free.fr/EFBindingTest.zip)

Note : I had to write a bit more code than expected, because of a limitation of SQL Server Compact : it doesn't support entity mapping to identity columns, so I had to manually generate a GUID instead... (in the `customerBindingSource_AddingNew` method). You might not need this code if the RDBMS you use supports it.

Comment: What db file do you refer to exactly? My EDM points to database in Sql Server and I would expect changes to be persisted to DB ie. new records should be visible as data in a table in a database.

Comment: OK, you're not using an attached .mdf file ?

Comment: Only after adding following code am I able to persist to DB. However, binding is still not working since data is not loaded initially. *** Public Class Form1 Dim ctx As Model1Container = New Model1Container() Private Sub CustomerBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CustomerBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click Dim c = Customer.CreateCustomer(IdTextBox.Text, FirstNameTextBox.Text, LastNameTextBox.Text) ctx.Customers.AddObject(c) ctx.SaveChanges() End Sub End Class ***

Comment: You need to set the BindingSource's DataSource property to an instance of the entity set : `customerBindingSource.DataSource = ctx.Customers;`

Comment: Even after setting the DataSource, the code is still flawed. It will work only if I press Save after adding each new item. If I add 3 in a row and press Save it will not work. **Could you by any chance post the whole code for this trivial example?**

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thanks for going through all this trouble. I added another line to CustomerBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click event handler: CustomerBindingSource.MoveFirst(). It seems that binding is not aware of the value you entered into the control until the control loses focus. I was getting NULL value exceptions from the DB on insert and that fixed the problem. I got a feeling VS 2010 is still quirky; it’s beta so I guess it’s understandable.

Comment: By default the binding updates the source when the control is validated (which happens, for instance, when it looses focus). You can change the properties of the bindings so that the source is immediately updated (PropertyChanged)